# Twin value tags as an esoteric taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I suspect the answer might be, get ready to write some SQL but I'm going to ask anyway.

I have a situation where I am pulling data from an outside source and storing it in a custom post type. For the main, this looks like it will work very well. However, there is a slight bump in the road.

The data comes with what are called stances. They exist as key-value pairs where key and value could be anything. Given that I store other data in the meta already, what I was hoping for was something like tags but in pairs. A taxonomy that works exactly like tags in most respects but has two values.

I toyed with converting the values into `$tag = "{$key}|{$value}";` but I can see that getting messy and bloated really fast.

The current solution puts the entire array into a single meta. It works but it is not great for "select all posts of type X that agree foo is bar".

Which brings me to ask if a more complex two-factor taxonomy is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing you could create a taxonomy for each unique stance key, then add the value as a term to the taxonomy for that key, then assign that term to the post.

I'd suggest something like:

1. Store the stance keys somewhere in the database (probably as options), making sure that you don't have duplicates. Depending on how many you have, this could probably just be a single value with a serialised array.
2. On the `init` hook, read the list of keys with `get_option()`, and register a taxonomy for each one with [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/).
3. When importing, save any new keys to the database, and immediately run `register_taxonomy()` for them so that the taxonomy is registered for the rest of the process.
4. For the values, add them as terms to the taxonomy using [`wp_insert_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/), but only after checking that value doesn't already exist with [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/).
5. Once the taxonomy has been registered, and the term for the value has been inserted or found, assign the term to the post using [`wp_set_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/).

If you do that then you can easily filter posts based on these values with a [taxonomy query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters). This will be faster than attempting to filter using post meta.

Comment: There is a certain genius to this. Could have a _lot_ of taxonomies but that's not the end of the world.

Comment: I further realised that I could (and maybe should) limit stance values to one of five possibles. If the possibles were the tax, there would be only five. Inside out, but should work.